# Google column chart customization

Tags: charts, customization

For example, i have chart that displays my weight changes by monthes.

Monthes goes on hAxis and weight values on vAxis

I have a few question:

1) How to set hAxis from 0 to, say, 70?
My initial weight was 70. I want to set hAxis baseline to this value. Thats allows me to show my weight changes. For example, in november it was 75 kgs (+5kgs) and this bar should go over the hAxis baseline. In december my weight equal 65 kgs (-5 kgs) and this bar should go under the hAxis baseline. Is it possible?

2) How to change bars fill color?

Comment: UPD: 1) Solved. Solution:  vAxis:{baseline:70}

Comment: If you found the solution yourself, you can put it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set vAxis baseline property to needed value:

```
vAxis:{baseline:70}
```

Comment: how can you change the baseline manually after the chart has been drawn?